# Help with problem player

Tags: problem-players

In my new group of coworkers, we're finding out that one of the players and his cleric are bringing the party down.

He's belittled the others, thrown them under the bus and even sacrificed one of the players' characters because he said "It's ok, I can just heal them".

The character is morally annoying and the player sees it all in video game perspective.

I've tried to teaching him a lesson in game by arresting them and giving him role playing scenarios to redeem himself but its not working.  Two of the four players are wanting to quit because of him.

I'm still awaiting a response from a message I sent him but I'm still worried.  What can I do to resolve the situation so that everyone is having fun?

Comment: The question seems to be "I am playing with a jerk and it's a problem, how do I solve that?" Am I right or is it more subtle?

Comment: *Two of the four players are wanting to quit because of him.*   Are you trying to get rid of him, keep them, or somehow keep him and them?  What is your goal?

Comment: @LegendaryDude The original post asked how to fix this.  It also explained that the OP saw the player in question's playstyle as a source of conflict.  Deciding that as part of the question they should ask how to change that playstyle rather than what to do since they have the playstyle is a non-trivial change to the original meaning.  We should not need to wait for the OP on that, the question should be returned to it's original meaning.  The rest of your edit is fine, so I think the format it was presented in is additionally misleading.  I don't want to get involved in an edit war, so...

Comment: ... I'm making a meta.  You can access it here: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6795/what-should-have-happened-here

Comment: I have rolled it back for the time being.  While improved I do not believe this is reopenable in its current state. @skeither7, you need to unpack a little more what about this is making the other players and yourself unhappy,  and what you all are (apparently implicitly) expecting out of the groups' play style.

Comment: Based on [a recent comment](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95825/help-with-problem-player#comment222630_95828), the question is confirmed incomplete, but the OP does not appear to have the intention of clarifying it. There's no point in reopening it then.

Answer (score 6):

As in the case with nearly every time you have a problem player...talk to him outside of the game.

He may be used to playing games with people that are okay with that kind of behavior (I've run into a few very backstabby parties in my time), and might be completely okay with the in-game ramifications of what he does. It might just be what he expects to be happening. So, it might not be a 'warning' in-game to him...it might just be the game working the way he expects it to.

That's the problem with in-game hints...people can miss what you are trying to say. Or they can interpret it as you being mean to them and punishing them for playing their character the way they want to.

So you need to make it clear that there's a problem. Tell him what you've told us, tell him what other players are saying, and ask if he is willing to tone it down a bit. He might honestly have no idea that the other players are so aggravated at him.

So, ultimately, you need to sit down and talk to him, privately, away from the rest of the group. Calmly explain what is going on, and see what he has to say.

He might apologize and shape up. He might laugh you off and ignore you. He might scream in your face...be ready for any of these possibilities.

But...if he doesn't shape up after you've talked to him and expressed that his behavior is not okay, it's time to put your foot down as the DM. If the polite approach doesn't work, then tell him something like this:

"I'm sorry to say this, then. But, as the DM, I need to make sure that the rest of the party is having fun, too. And they aren't. Because of you. If you are not willing to play with us in a way that we can all enjoy...I'm afraid I'm going to have to ask you to leave the game."

Give him a chance again, here, to promise to shape up.

But, that's your final option. As DM, you have the authority to expel a player from your game who is causing problems. It is better to expel a single player than to see the rest of the group abandon ship, leaving you stuck with the problem player.

So, short version:

Talk to him in private, explain to him that his behavior is making other players want to quit. Ask him if he's willing to change. If he refuses...it's time to ask him to leave the group. Be polite the entire time.

Comment: SO I talked to him after I posted this and it turns out theres some underlying social issues that were brought up and understood by everyone and things should smooth out now that the group has all talked about it